# JQuery 1.7.2 focus event pops always before blur event on same selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

I've made some code to restrict tab navigation on some elements of my choice. You can see the full code working here : http://jsfiddle.net/M2ELL/2/ it's working fine.

The thing is I want to "decorate" the parent div where the focus occurs. For that matter I've made these event listener :

```
$('[data-mymodaltabindex]').blur(function () {        
   $(this).parent().removeClass('highlight');
   console.log('blur ' + $(this));
});

$('[data-mymodaltabindex]').focus(function () {
   $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
   console.log('highlight ' + $(this));
});
```

These work as expected when there is only one input per parent div. On the other hand when there is two input per parent div (like the two radios in my example) the focus event occurs always before the blur event. The result is highlighting then removing the highlight on the div which is the opposite that I want.

I would like the blur event to occur before resulting in remove highlight then highlight. How can I achieve that ? Why focus event always occurs before blur event in this case ?

Full Code :

```
<div>
    radio 1
    <input type="radio" data-mymodaltabindex="1" />
    radio 2
    <input type="radio" data-mymodaltabindex="2" />
</div>
<div>
    text
    <input type="text" data-mymodaltabindex="3" />
</div>

$('[data-mymodaltabindex]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which == 9) {
        // define variables
        var mytabindex = null;
        var maximum = null;
        var minimum = null;
        var next = null;
        var previous = null;
        var values = new Array();
        // set mytabindex on the actual focused control
        var mytabindex = $(this).attr('data-mymodaltabindex');
        // put every visible mytabindex into array
        $('[data-mymodaltabindex]:visible').each(function () {
            values.push(parseInt($(this).attr('data-mymodaltabindex')));
        });
        //console.log(values);
        // look for maximum minimum mytabindex 
        // for maximum and minimum we filter out null values 
        // as they are interpreted as 0 with math functions
        maximum = Math.max.apply(null, values.filter(function (val) { return val !== null }));
        minimum = Math.min.apply(null, values.filter(function (val) { return val !== null }));
        // set next and previous using function
        next = getModalClosestHighValue(values, mytabindex);
        previous = getModalClosestLowValue(values, mytabindex);
        // go back to begining / end if 
        // end / begining is reached
        if (!previous) { previous = maximum; }
        if (!next) { next = minimum; }
        // check if there is shift combination
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            mytabindex = previous; // focus on the previous item
        } else {
            mytabindex = next; // focus on the next item
        }
        // focus on this element
        $('[data-mymodaltabindex=' + mytabindex + ']').focus();
        console.log('focus set to [data-mymodaltabindex=' + mytabindex + ']');
        // stop propagation
        return false;
    }
});

function getModalClosestHighValue(a, x) {
    var hi;
    for (var i = a.length; i--; ) {
        if (a[i] > x && (hi === undefined || hi > a[i])) hi = a[i];
    };
    return hi;
}

function getModalClosestLowValue(a, x) {
    var lo;
    for (var i = a.length; i--; ) {
        if (a[i] < x && (lo === undefined || lo < a[i])) lo = a[i];
    };
    return lo;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Chrome/linux or Firefox/linux : http://jsfiddle.net/7mfLb/

Comment: On what browser do you have the problem ?

Comment: Jquery version differs ... in your fiddle you are using 1.9 in mine it's 1.72

Comment: So... I'd suggest updating your jQuery :)

Comment: I've just tried but I can't it's too complicated with all depedencies with other modules. I have to make it work with this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's a bug with some jQuery versions that can be solved by using jQuery 1.9.

Works with 1.9 : http://jsfiddle.net/7mfLb/

Doesn't work with 1.8.3 : http://jsfiddle.net/dHwE5/

---

If you want to make it work with 1.7.2, then I propose you this workaround :

```
$('[data-mymodaltabindex]').on('blur focus', function() {
   var $p = $(this).parent();
   $p.removeClass('highlight');
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('div :has(:focus)', $p.parent()).addClass('highlight');
   }, 0);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/qkJcS/)

Comment: thanks again but like i said I have to make it work with 1.72

Comment: Why ? Do you really have dependencies to this version ? It's dangerous to keep tied to an old version. Your priority should be to solve those (buggy) dependencies.

Comment: I use the jquery-validate.js plugin that raise errors when i try using 1.9

Comment: Oh thanks but still it won't work there is no more highlight using your code : http://jsfiddle.net/M2ELL/4/

Comment: @Arno2501 Did you try the fiddle I linked to ?